# Angular amTimeAgo not refreshing

Tags: angular, angular2-moment

I am trying to refresh amTimeAgo every time I call my function "resetDate" but it is not working. It is logging a correct new time in the console but the time does not refresh on the page.

```
    import { NgModule, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

    export class AppComponent {
       getSystemsStatus () {
         this.httpClient.get<serverResponse>('http://127.0.0.1:5000/systemsStatus').subscribe(data => {
        if (JSON.stringify(this.systemStatusText) === JSON.stringify(data.systemStatusText)) {

        }
        else {
          this.systemStatus=data.systemStatus;
          this.systemStatusText=data.systemStatusText;
          let callTimeagoComponent = new TimeagoComponent();
          callTimeagoComponent.resetDate();
        }
        });
    };
  }
}

    @Component({
          selector: 'lastUpdated',
          template: '<div id="time1"><time>Last updated: {{myDate | amTimeAgo}}</time>'
        })

        export class TimeagoComponent{
          myDate = new Date();
          resetDate() {
            this.myDate = new Date();
          }
        }


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MomentModule
      ],
      declarations: [ TimeagoComponent ],
      bootstrap: [ TimeagoComponent ]
    })
    class TimeagoModule {}

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(TimeagoModule);
```

What am I missing? I am just trying to compare the results of two items returned from the HTTP call, and if they are different, update the items and refresh the time since last updated.

Comment: can you share your child time  component code

Comment: @Chellappan I updated the code. The other class I have makes HTTP calls but doesn't deal with amTimeAgo except to call resetDate()

Comment: how do you upadating ui without calling resetDate()

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that trying to simplify where I thought the problem was but I can see that made it confusing. I added where I am calling the resetData() function.

Comment: in angular if you want to share data you have to use service or input,output property binding

Comment: I don't necessarily need to share data. The variable "myDate" only exists in the class "TimeagoComponent". I am just trying to reset that and amTimeAgo when I call the function "resetDate()" from the separate class "AppComponent", but I do not need any data passed from one class to the other.